# Bootstrap 5 navbar dropdown only opens and doesn't closes

Tags: html, css, frontend, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a website and I am using it to create a dropdown in my navbar. When you hover over the dropdown on a desktop it's supposed to open and when you are on mobile and you click the dropdown it is supposed to open and when you click it again it's supposed to close, but right now it is only opening.

##Test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Navbar</title>
    <!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dropdown.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
            <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
          </a>
  
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggler"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navmenu"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
          </button>
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
  
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false" id="">
            Services
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
            <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
            
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Contact</a></li>
  
          <script>
            // Get the Services dropdown link element
            const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
          
            // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
              window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
            });
          
            // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
            if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
              // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
              servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
              });
          
              // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
              servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
              });
            }
          </script>
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
  
          <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION START -->
      
          <!-- <button 
            type="button" 
            class="btn btn-primary" 
            data-bs-toggle="modal" 
            data-bs-target="#loginmodal"
          >
            Login/Signup
          </button>
          <div id="loginmodal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <button
                   
                    type="button" 
                    class="btn-close btn-close-white" 
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
                  ></button>
                  <div class="myform bg-dark">
                    <h1 class="text-center" id="modal-styling">Login Form</h1>
                    <form action="#">
                      <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="passeord" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mt-3">LOGIN</button>
                      <p id="modal-styling">Don't have an account? <a href="#" id="modal-styling">Signup</a> </p>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->
      <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION CLOSE -->
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
        </div>
      
      </nav>
      <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->
</body>
</html>
```

### Test.css

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}


#nav_object {
    position: relative;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}

#dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
    color: white !important;
    }


#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.nav-link {
    position: relative;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}

#nav_object::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    #nav_object:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
    border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}


#nav_object {
    position: relative;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}

#dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
    color: white !important;
    }


#navbar-color {
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.nav-link {
    position: relative;
}


.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}

#nav_object::after {
        content: '';
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.2s;
        height: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        background: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    
    #nav_object:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Navbar</title>
    <!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dropdown.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" /> -->

<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
        <div class="container">
          <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
            <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
          </a>
  
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
          <button
            type="button"
            class="navbar-toggler"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navmenu"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
          </button>
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
  
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false" id="">
            Services
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
            <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
            <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
            
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Contact</a></li>
  
          <script>
            // Get the Services dropdown link element
            const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
          
            // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
              window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
            });
          
            // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
            if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
              // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
              servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
                this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
              });
          
              // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
              servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
                this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
              });
            }
          </script>
          <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
  
          <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION START -->
      
          <!-- <button 
            type="button" 
            class="btn btn-primary" 
            data-bs-toggle="modal" 
            data-bs-target="#loginmodal"
          >
            Login/Signup
          </button>
          <div id="loginmodal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <button
                   
                    type="button" 
                    class="btn-close btn-close-white" 
                    data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
                  ></button>
                  <div class="myform bg-dark">
                    <h1 class="text-center" id="modal-styling">Login Form</h1>
                    <form action="#">
                      <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="passeord" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mt-3">LOGIN</button>
                      <p id="modal-styling">Don't have an account? <a href="#" id="modal-styling">Signup</a> </p>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->
      <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION CLOSE -->
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
        </div>
      
      </nav>
      <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run the code, it does close for me, I'm not sure what is causing your issue.

Comment: @Jordan i have been having the same issue with other files as well; for certain files it works for others but not for me

Comment: It is impossible for me to help if you don't have a reproduceable example, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if you're talking about the services navbar not closing when you click it, it might be because your css .dropdown:hover is messing with bootstrap's css.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}
```

also, you have unnecessary duplicates in your codes.